# Vertical Alignment differences for Webkit vs. Mozilla

Tags: html, css, webkit, alignment, mozilla

Alright, so in Mozilla my website looks as I intended. However, in webkit browsers, h1 and h2 elements are shifted down by about 4px. What's the deal?

http://wbjah.com/stackoverflow.htm

```
h1 {
color: #739e39;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0px;
}

h1 a:hover{
color: #739e39;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #739e39;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
color: #739e39;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 40px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I see no difference between the two.

Comment: What versions of Chrome and Firefox are you using?

Comment: If you're using FF4 then I can see some issues arising. FF4 seems pretty buggy at the moment. Looks the same for me in FF3.6 and Chrome.

Comment: ah, yes. I use FF4, I just assumed FF3 and 4 rendered the same.
For me, in FF, the j in Wbjah is just barely sitting on top of the border below it. In webkit browsers, the bottom of the j is overlapping the border.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using `inline-block` instead of `float`, as that avoids having to fiddle around with `line-height`.

1. Delete the `<br>` before `motto here`
2. Change `#headbox` from `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;`
3. Delete the `line-height: 50px;` from `h1`
4. Delete the `height: 50px;` from `#header`

Comment: Agreed, don't use line-height for layout. Set line-height to normal, or 1 (no units) and use margin/padding to control height. Otherwise there will be differences in browsers.